# Select a specified JTable row and then play a sound?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, event-dispatch-thread

I have the following code (edited slightly) which successfully selects a row in my JTable. The routine that plays a sound also works perfectly - this is commented out in the code below. When I uncomment that line, the row selection does not show visibly anymore until the code stops executing. What can I change to make the row change happen visibly first, and then the sound plays until we get to the last row?
Thanks.

```
    while (rowToSelect < totalRows)    
    {
        try {
            table.setRowSelectionInterval(rowToSelect, rowToSelect);
            //PlaySound = new PlaySound(soundToPlay);
            rowToSelect++;
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: *When I uncomment that line, the row selection does not show visibly anymore until the code stops executing* - the music needs to execute on a separate Thread, so you don't prevent the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) from repainting the table selection.

Comment: Will this still allow the operations to happen sequentially? The sound should only play after the row has been selected?

Comment: You will need logic to implement this. As a row is selected you would add the row to a Queue. As each song finishes playing you get the next song in the queue and play it.